# Binding breaks after button click

Tags: wpf, xaml

Consider the following xaml code.

```
<TextBox x:Name="txtbox1" Grid.Row="1" Background="Aqua" Height="33" Width="55" Text="45"/>
<Button Content="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=Self}, Path=Height}"
        Click="bttn_Click"   x:Name="bttn" 
        Height="{Binding ElementName=txtbox1, Path=Text, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, Mode=OneWay}"
        Grid.Row="2" />
```

And `bttn_Click` as follows,

```
private void bttn_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    double randomNo = 10;
    Random random = new Random();
    randomNo = random.Next(45,85);
    this.bttn.Height = randomNo;
}
```

After I click the `Button`, the value updated in target. But after that when I entered the value in `TextBox` the value is not updated to target.

Comment: What `Textbox` are you talking about?

Comment: First you likely need to be bound to a property. Second you probably need to implement INotifyPropertyChanged so the UI refreshes when the property is updated. 

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.inotifypropertychanged(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Height is a dependency property. Since its value might be "set" in multiple places, there is a [precendence list](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/advanced/dependency-property-value-precedence).

Setting directly its value (local value) has a priority on the binding.
In the link I provided it is clearly stated:

> any change to the local value replaces the dynamic resource or binding
>   entirely

Comment: Do you know of any way to set the local value in code-behind while preserving the binding? I have had a similar issue.

Comment: IHMO @Jack you can try to update your `Binding`'s source. In this case you can change the `Text` property of the _txtbox1_ `TextBox`. The `Binding` will do the work for you

Answer (score 0):

Your `bttn_Click` event updates your `Button` height, but it does not update to the height entered in your `Textbox` like you wanted, as your binding would suggest.

To conserve both actions I suggest binding your `Button` Height property to the `Text` value of your `Textbox`, like you have done, but use a Converter to parse the string into an int/double.

**Converter**

```
public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter,
        CultureInfo culture)
    {
        var text = (string)value;

        return Int32.Parse(text);
    }
```

and then your `Button` height to:

```
Height="{Binding ElementName=txtbox1, Path=Text,
Converter={StaticResource TextToIntConverter},
UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, Mode=OneWay}"
```

Note: The height will only update when the Text is validated, depending on how you configure it.

Answer (score 0):

Setting the `Height` property programmatically effectively clears the binding that you have defined in your XAML markup.

You should change the height by setting the source property of the binding, i.e. the `Text` property of the `TextBox`:

```
private void bttn_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    double randomNo = 10;
    Random random = new Random();
    randomNo = random.Next(45, 85);
    this.txtbox1.Text = randomNo.ToString();
}
```

The other option would be to set the `Mode` of the `Binding` to `TwoWay`:

```
<Button Content="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=Self}, Path=Height}"
        Click="bttn_Click"   x:Name="bttn" 
        Height="{Binding ElementName=txtbox1, Path=Text, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, Mode=TwoWay}"
        Grid.Row="2" />
```

This works because `TwoWay` bindings, unline `OneWay` bindings, are *not* cleared when you set the property programmatically.